# Does SceneKit work any more in macOS Catalyst apps?

Tags: macos, scenekit, macos-catalina

I installed macOS Catalina Beta 6 and Xcode 11 Beta 6, and our SceneKit-based Catalyst app has completely stopped displaying nodes. It logs errors for most/all geometries. Does anyone know if there is a solution or workaround? Did I install Xcode wrong somehow?

```
2019-08-20 11:26:46.052986-0700 App[16236:879002] [SceneKit] Error: Compiler error while building render pipeline state for node <C3DNode:0x1021219a0 "Cube"
geometry: <C3DParametricGeometry<Box>:0x102121ad0 "box"
 mesh: <C3DMesh 0x600003b27800 "(null)"
 element0: <C3DMeshElement 0x600003b271e0 type:triangles primCount:12 channels:1 indexBytes:2 offset:0 acmr:2.000000 inst:1 dataSize:72 shared:0x0>
 source position (channel:0) : <C3DMeshSource 0x6000029597a0(position) data:(0x600000d3d830) mut:0 count:24 type:float3 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:0 stride:32>
 source normal (channel:0) : <C3DMeshSource 0x600002959960(normal) data:(0x600000d3d830) mut:0 count:24 type:float3 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:12 stride:32>
 source texcoord (channel:0) : <C3DMeshSource 0x6000029598f0(texcoord) data:(0x600000d3d830) mut:0 count:24 type:float2 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:24 stride:32>
 renderable element0: <C3DMeshElement 0x600003b271e0 type:triangles primCount:12 channels:1 indexBytes:2 offset:0 acmr:2.000000 inst:1 dataSize:72 shared:0x0>
 renderable source position: <C3DMeshSource 0x6000029597a0(position) data:(0x600000d3d830) mut:0 count:24 type:float3 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:0 stride:32>
 renderable source normal: <C3DMeshSource 0x600002959960(normal) data:(0x600000d3d830) mut:0 count:24 type:float3 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:12 stride:32>
 renderable source texcoord: <C3DMeshSource 0x6000029598f0(texcoord) data:(0x600000d3d830) mut:0 count:24 type:float2 divisor:0 mtl:0 offset:24 stride:32>
```

>
    mat0: >
  >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a Metal compiler issue in macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta 6.
It should be fixed in a future beta version.

Comment: It's now working correctly in macOS Catalina 10.15 beta 7.